# Image recoginiton and clicking on the screen

Tags: python

i need python libraries to make a bot that will recognize an image of the button and  click on it, button's position is randomized every click.
it should collect the image and click by itself, without user interaction

i have used OpenCV in the past, but i do not know how to automate the clicking on the screen